# Evaluating an infinite series using partial fractions...

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

I am having trouble evaluating an infinite series that uses partial fractions.  The problem is as follows:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\left(n + 1\right)\left(n + 2\right)}
$$

I realize that this is a telescoping series, but I am unable to find a general formula for the Sn.

After the partial fraction decomposition the problem looks like
$1/\left(2n\right) - 1/\left(n + 1\right) + 1/\left(2n + 4\right)$. I input values for $n = 1, n = 2,$ etc, and some cancel out but I am unable to determine a pattern to write to find Sn...  Thanks.

I found this answer to the problem online which makes sense, up to the step where it makes Sn equal to
$1/2(1/2 - 1/\left(n+1\right) + 1/\left(n+2\right)$.  I get the prior steps but I am not sure how they make that leap.

[image]

Comment: You have a typo. Quote:"1/2n - 1/(n+1) + 1/(2n+2)" Please make an edit. It is 1/(2n) - 1/(n+1) + 1/(2n+$\color{red}4$)

Comment: Besides the central sum, I add $\texttt{\left}$ and $\texttt{\right}$ as need it. I didn't check the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{(n+1)} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$$

So

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1(1+1)}-\frac{1}{(1+1)(1+2)}+\frac{1}{2(2+1)}-\frac{1}{(2+1)(2+2)}+\cdots\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Why did you multiply 1/(n+1) by 1/2(1/n -1/(n+2) in the first row?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2} = \frac{n+2}{n(n+2)} - \frac{n}{n(n+2)} = \frac{2}{n(n+2)}$

Comment: Oh.  Did you not use partial fraction decomposition? And I'm not sure how you arrived at 1/2 * 1/2 at the end...

Comment: I managed to get the same answer by writing out the terms of the sequence and then cancelling out those that repeated.  I ended with 1/8 + 1/8, so 1/4.

Comment: Is the goal to get two terms rather than three (Does that make it easier to notice the telescoping series?)

Comment: The second $\frac{1}{2}$ was from $\frac{1}{1(1+1)}$

Comment: And yes, the goal was that, since we know the value for the telescoping series of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$, we try to express $\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$ in the form of $\frac{1}{a(a+1)}$.